# Impressão de Página

Tags: javascript, arquivo, impressão, modal

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de contar quantas vezes uma determinada página (html) foi impressa. Sei que podemos contar as vezes que uma modal foi aberta com o click do botão, nesta mesma modal tenho um botão para imprimir (o conteúdo dela), mas preciso contar quantas vezes aquele conteúdo foi de fato impresso. Isso é possível?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54262/discussion-on-question-by-let-impressao-de-pagina)

Answer (score 3):

Não.

Você pode apenas contar quantas vezes o usuário clicou no seu botão de imprimir. Caso isso seja suficiente: da mesma forma como você incrementa o contador de aberturas do modal, você pode incrementar o contador de cliques do botão de imprimir. Você pode fazer algo como assim:

HTML:

```
<button id="botaoPraImprimir" type="button">Imprimir</button>
<input type="hidden" id="contadorDeImpressoes" value="0">
```

Javascript, com jQuery:

```
var $contadorImpressoes = $("#contadorImpressoes");
$("#botaoPraImprimir").on("click", function () {
    let valorAtual = parseInt($contadorImpressoes).val();
    $contadorImpressoes.val(valorAtual + 1);
});
```

Note que isso vai contar quantas vezes o botão de imprimir **do seu modal** foi impresso. Assim você sabe quantas vezes o usuário teve a **intenção de imprimir**.

O botão de imprimir do diálogo de impressão do navegador não é acessível via código - e não existe evento de impressão do navegador que você possa capturar ou interceptar. Você não tem como contar quantas vezes um documento foi **impresso de fato**, nem **quantas cópias foram feitas**.